# How can I disable Intel Active Management Technology if my BIOS has no toggle for it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bios

I have an Alienware Aurora R4, with no BIOS option to disable Intel AMT. Are there any other ways in which I can disable this on my PC? Its causing some huge issues for me on Windows 10, and I find it to be very creepy software that allows remote connections via hardware support with sub-kernel level clearance. No thanks.

My issue with it, aside from it being a security risk, is that Windows 10 keeps pushing a driver update for it on my machine with no way for me to stop it (Windows 10 has a bug in it whereby ticking the box to stop it from pushing driver updates does not work, nor can Windows 10 updates be deferred or stopped; it auto-forces people to update drivers, even with Enterprise Edition or the long service branch of Enterprise, unfortunately). The driver for it causes my machine to stop responding when booting, and I had to recently reformat my PC because of it, losing all my apps, data and files.

I want it gone. I want AMT to be nuked from my machine.

Comment: Alienware Aurora R4 (i.e. Intel X79) doesn't support Intel AMT.

Comment: Clarify which CPU you have specifically.  Just having a laptop model isn't enough to explain the behavior you describe.

Comment: AMT is an function of the ME; you can have the ME without AMT enabled.  To avoid driver problems, you should go get the latest ME driver directly from Intel and try that.

Comment: @Ramhound Intel Core i7 3960X

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Intel doesn't support or have any drivers on their site for Alienware's ME. No installer they supply for ME drivers works from their site. Aside: This driver may cause me to have to reformat my PC again; now that its stable I don't want to risk it.

Comment: @RomanSevko Maybe; I'm not so sure...hard to say what its intended purpose is because the device exists on the motherboard, and Dell has released driver updates for it (why release a driver for a useless device?): http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=7K3DG&fileId=3335201959&osCode=WB64A&productCode=alienware-aurora-r4&languageCode=EN&categoryId=CS

Comment: @Alexandru - Waiting on the question to be updated.  The question honestly is confusing.  If you don't want AMT then, don't install the driver, if it cannot be disabled in BIOS that is up to Dell to support.  Without a driver Windows won't use AMT.

Comment: @Ramhound You are familiar with AMT, yes? So you know it has a dedicated hardware TCP/IP stack. It seems to allow remote connections through hardware, so it should not matter if an OS is installed. Doesn't the BIOS load this device before the OS to allow remote connections? If so, does the device not have its own BIOS configuration utility that you can get into? I am not entirely sure, but some posts online would have me believe AMT has its own BIOS UI. I was wondering if there was a way in its own software to disable it.

Comment: I thought I knew what it was, given Intel names everything Intel active something I thought it was something but I still maintain if no services are installed then it effectively disabled.

Answer (score -1):

Alienware Aurora R4 (i.e. Intel X79) doesn't support Intel AMT.
[Prooflink](http://vpro.by/img/X79-does-not-support-intel-amt.jpg).

Comment: Oh my...we've been down this road before. How does this answer the question, man? Windows 10 still tries to push the driver to me, the device still shows up in Device Manager, and Dell even releases custom drivers for this hardware device. I think its wonderful that you are trying so hard to prove me wrong, but facts are facts, and you are honestly wasting your time.

Comment: You can't disable Intel AMT on your Intel X79 sytem because it hasn't got it. There is only Intel ME.